# Displaying reference pictures to a varying value in QField

Tags: qfield, widget, attachments

While developing a QField project for forestry inventories, I aim at displaying botany board related to the current selected species selected in a scrolling-menu for field operator. It should be used as a reference to compare with the species suspected on the field. I followed this procedure : https://qfield.org/docs/prepare/add-1-n-pictures.html

Here is the referencing layer as a table containing pathes for the pictures related to the species named "photos_essence.csv"

[image]

Here is the referenced layer "Qfield_comptage.shp" used for digitizing.

[image]

In the project properties, i added a relation "photos_essence" between the referenced layer "Qfield_comptage.shp" and the referencing layer "photos_essence.csv". It should be linking species ("Essence") identified and the path to the pictures related to those species.

[image]

I added the relation "photos_essence" in  Attribute Form of the "Qfield_comptage.shp" referenced layer.

[image]

Then I changed the widget type to attachment, linking it to the file containing the pictures

[image]

The end result gives a null value instead of displaying the pictures related to the species identified.

[image]

Do you have any insight of what i'm doing wrong ?

I do not know if such a widget is conceivable.

Comment: In Properties, your relation is called pictures-essences. But your relation widget is called photo. How is this? The relation widget should have the same name as the relation. This suggests your examples are from different projects. Check your details.

Comment: But that inhibits us helping you. It's all about detail. Check it, double check it and if it's still not working post the actual settings so we can review.

Answer (score 1):

Check...is "essence" unique in "Qfield_comptage.shp". It MUST be. I would recommend not using "essence" and the foreign key in your child table, instead use [Qfield_comptage].[ID].

If you want to send an example project over, I'm happy to look more closely.